# pip search showed apache-beam 2.9 but pip install apache-beam only get apache-beam2.2 installed

Tags: pip, apache-beam

In my fresh new virtual environment.

I run

```
pip search apache-beam
```

I got

```
apache-beam (2.9.0)
```

Then I run

```
pip install apache-beam
pip list
```

But I got apache-beam 2.2 installed, instead of 2.9

```
apache-beam    2.2.0
```

I then run

```
 python -m apache_beam.examples.wordcount --output cout
```

I got the error

```
 The Apache Beam SDK for Python is supported only on Python 2.7.
```

From this document

https://towardsdatascience.com/hands-on-apache-beam-building-data-pipelines-in-python-6548898b66a5

beam 2.9 will support python3. But pip search I found apache-beam 2.9. but pip install, I still get apache-beam 2.2.

Please help.

Comment: Try `pip uninstall apache-beam && pip install apache-beam==2.9.0`.

Comment: Also, keep in mind that Python 3 is not yet supported ([source](https://jira.apache.org/jira/browse/BEAM-1251)). The article talks about 2.9.0 SDK fixing the Snappy [issue](https://github.com/apache/beam/pull/6801)

Comment: pip install apache-beam==2.9.0

I got the result: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement apache-beam==2.9.0 (from versions: 0.6.0, 2.0.0, 2.1.0, 2.1.1, 2.2.0)
No matching distribution found for apache-beam==2.9.0

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got the same kind of requirement, I tried this way to install apache Beam
it was worked for me.

Step 01: Make sure to install python 3.7 or above
Step 02: Beam version, I choose 2.27 for my requirement

```
pip3 install apache-beam==2.27.0
```